# Hive cannot connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, hive

I'm trying to install Hive on my virtual machine, and Hadoop and MySQL have been installed successfully. I follow the instruction to add a mysql-connector-java.jar into `/usr/local/hive/lib`, however, it didn't work. It always said failed to load driver. The `hive` database have been successfully created in MySQL.

I'm using openjdk (version 1.8.0_312), hive (version 3.1.2) and Hadoop (version 3.3.1).

Please give me some help, thank you.

`schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema --verbose`

```sh
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Metastore connection URL:        jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hive
Metastore Connection Driver :    com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Metastore connection User:       root
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
Underlying cause: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaException: Failed to load driver
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.tools.HiveSchemaHelper.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaHelper.java:97)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:169)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.testConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaTool.java:475)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:581)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.doInit(HiveSchemaTool.java:567)
        at org.apache.hive.beeline.HiveSchemaTool.main(HiveSchemaTool.java:1517)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.tools.HiveSchemaHelper.getConnectionToMetastore(HiveSchemaHelper.java:85)
        ... 11 more
*** schemaTool failed ***
```

`hive`

```sh
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hbase/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.10.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.30.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Hive Session ID = 4a4a5ab1-5ac3-4228-85cc-7ac2f91dda8d

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/hive-common-3.1.2.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getTimeDuration(Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;Ljava/util/concurrent/TimeUnit;)J
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.impl.DfsClientConf.<init>(DfsClientConf.java:249)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:324)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:308)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initDFSClient(DistributedFileSystem.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3354)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3403)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3371)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:477)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:226)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:624)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:591)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:747)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:683)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

Comment: How do you know you're using the correct file path for modifying the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

It's turns out to be that the version of mysql connector is not compatibale, the problem is solved after reinstall correct version.